# A question about rings of integers and its prime ideals

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $b\in\mathcal{O}_K^*$. Then is there a good reason to believe that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, we can pick some natural number $n$ such that $1+bn$ is 0 modulo $\mathfrak{p}$? This came up on a research paper that I am working on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, this just means that $b$ maps to the prime subfield of the residue field, which should be generally false unless $\mathfrak{p}$ has inertia degree $1$, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If $K$ is such that $\mathcal{O}_K^*=\{\pm 1\}$, then this is true (for any $\mathfrak{p}$, we can take n=p-1 or n=1, respectively, for b=1 or b=-1, where $p=\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$). Is there any way for this to be true for other fields, for example cyclotomic fields?

Comment: This should also hold for Gaussian integers, although checking it might be time consuming.

Comment: For Gaussian integers, it fails for $b=\pm i$ modulo all primes $p\equiv3\pmod4$. But you have a point with the $\mathcal O_K^\times=\{\pm1\}$ cases.

Comment: It fails for all primes of inertia degree $>1$ whenever $\mathcal  O_K=\mathbb Z[\mathcal  O_K^\times]$, which includes all cyclotomic fields.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Good point. I think I need a different approach to this. Can we always say that sum of three units, none of which are additive inverses of each other, must be a non-unit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147051/discussion-between-shyamalsayak-and-emil-jerabek).

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t know this, and algebraic number theory is not really my field. It’s possible that you can find this in the literature on the unit equation.

Comment: Oh, but actually, whenever the unit equation $u+v=1$ has a solution other than a 6th root of unity, $u+uv+v^2=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: In the Field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ take the unit $i$ and the prime 3, which is inert, so the residue field in $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{-1})$. The unit $i$ mapsto $\sqrt{-1}$ and thus is a counterexample.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: If $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$, which is a unit, then $1+\phi+\phi^3=\phi^2+\phi^3=\phi^4$ is a unit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is a very nice example. Thank you.